# DFS algorithm (directed graph)

Tags: graphs

If you have a back edge in a directed graph, then you may have a cycle or must have a cycle?

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried proving that there must be a cycle? Have you tried finding an example in which there is no cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Back edge is a method to detect cycle in the directed graph.